# twitter bootstrap with Django 1.3

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am using Pythoneverywhere.com to deploy my django app, which is why I am using Django ver 1.3. I am trying to use twitter bootstrap..with no luck so far.

I unzipped bootstrap.zip in static folder, so it's there. And below is what my template head looks like:

```
{% load static %}
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="{% get_static_prefix %}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="{% get_static_prefix %}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

This doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. What should I do instead?

Comment: Why not just load Bootstrap's css and js from bootstrapcdn.com? You'll still need to properly configure serving other static files for your app, but serving static media from a CDN is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) guide, you need to configure your static files.

add `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in your `settings.py`

your project directory should be

`project/
    --app/
    --template
    --static/`

And your template should be :-

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" ></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you @Anish. It is how I used to do it when I was running the app on localhost with Django ver 1.5, but somehow it still isn't working.. :/